# Hide and unhide a text after 6 and 1 seconds (Html) Infinite loop

Tags: text, hide, show, getelementbyid

Hi i have created this script to show a text for 1 second and hide a text for 6 seconds, but now i would do the opposite , what i would do now is to hide the text for the first 6 seconds and then only 1 second of showed text , so on to the infinity that never stops , how I can create this kind of html script?

```html
<h1 style="text-align: left;" id="xhide">Hello World</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flag=0;
function hide(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id);
    d.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
}

function show(id) {
    d= document.getElementById(id)
    d.setAttribute('style','display:block;')
}

setInterval(function() {
    if(flag==6) {
        show('xhide');
        flag = 0 ;
    } else {
       hide('xhide');
       flag++;
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout calling another setTimeout that would make an infinite loop:

```
function startWithHide(id) {
    hide(id);
    setTimeout(function() { startWithShow(id); }, 6000);
}

function startWithShow(id) {
    show(id);
    setTimeou(function() { startWithHide(id); }, 1000);
}
```